# how to give "\n" character in label text?

Tags: iphone

I have coded like that, but can't get output:

```
label.text = @"hai\nyou";
```

but the output is `hai you`. I want: `hai` and then `you` must be in the next line.

Answer (score 3):

```
...
label.text = @"hai\nyou";
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the "# of Lines" to 0 and let me know if it works.

Or, if you are typing in the little box in IB use option-return to insert a line feed (\n).